# How to get values from an executed batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, roundhouse

I'm trying to set up a barebones roundhousE setup, with a few touches. I'm trying to make the values used by roundhousE set in one central location, instead of each deployment batch script (which is a pain in the arse). However, when I reference the `SetupVal.bat` from each deployment batch, it sets the values but just stops executing the deployment script. I'm not sure why it doesn't carry on, and it's really annoying me.

This is my `SetupVal.bat`:

```
SET product.name="####"
SET database.name="%product.name%.DB"
SET sql.files.directory="..\db\SQLServer"
SET server.database="(local)\SQLEXPRESS"
SET repository.path="git@roconnor:%product.name%.git"
SET version.file="_BuildInfo.xml"
SET version.xpath="//buildInfo/version"
SET environment="LOCAL"
```

this is one of my scripts (the `Local.DBDeployment.bat`):

```
@echo off

cd ..
SetupVal.bat
cd deployment
REM this is to make sure the path is correctly set out

"%cd%\Console\rh.exe" /d=%database.name% /f=%sql.files.directory% /s=%server.database% /vf=%version.file% /vx=%version.xpath% /r=%repository.path% /env=%environment% /simple

pause
```

This is the output when I run `Local.DBDeployment.bat`:

```
C:\dev\Database>SetupValues.bat

C:\dev\Database>SET product.name="####"

C:\dev\Database>SET database.name=""####".DB"

C:\dev\Database>SET sql.files.directory="..\db\SQLServer"

C:\dev\Database>SET server.database="(local)\SQLEXPRESS"

C:\dev\Database>SET repository.path="git@roconnor:"####".git"

C:\dev\Database>SET version.file="_BuildInfo.xml"

C:\dev\Database>SET version.xpath="//buildInfo/version"

C:\dev\Database>SET environment="LOCAL"
```

And finally, this is my directory structure:

```
Database (root)
|
 \_db (SQL scripts are here)
 |_deployment (bat scripts are here)
 |_settings (ignoring contents)
 |_SetupVal.bat (This sets the values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you execute `SetupVal.bat`, control is given to that file. there is no return, so if `setval.bat` ends, the complete batch-structure ends. Instead call your file:

```
call SetupVal.bat
```

Your initial batchfile will continue with the next line, when `setupval.bat` ends and returns control

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant!